# Cannot find module @angular/core with latest final release of Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have copied package.json and tsconfig.json from 
[Official angular quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

but node_modules is not getting downloaded. I'm receiving error as Cannot find module @angular/core when used in Component  as follows

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
```

**Note** : using Node.js version 6.7.0 and npm version 3.10.3
IDE : Visual Studio

Comment: what configuration you have in `systemjs.config.js`?

Comment: have you run `npm install` ?

Comment: I have run npm install but I see error as package.json file not found, it is expecting in thw place where we have sln file, but it will be inside our project , So as temporary solution I copied that there , Is There any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger npm install in the same folder that your package.json file exists.

Comment: I have run npm install but I see error as package.json file not found, it is expecting in thw place where we have sln file, but it will be inside our project , So as temporary solution I copied that there , Is There any solution for this?